# Sort an array by a child array's value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array composed of arrays. I want to sort the parent array by a property of the child arrays. Here's an example

```
array(2){
    [0]=> array(3){
        [0]=> string(6) "105945"
        [1]=> string(10) "First name"
        [2]=> float(0.080878465391)
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(6) "109145"
        [1]=> string(11) "Second name"
        [2]=> float(0.0504154818384)
    }
}
```

I would like to sort the parent array by `[2]` ascending in the child arrays, so in this case the result would be the child arrays reversed (`.05`, `08`).  Is this possible using any of the numerous PHP sort functions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can make use of [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function as:

```
$arr = array(
    array("105945", "First name", 0.080878465391),
    array("109145", "Second name", 0.0504154818384)
);

function cmp($a, $b){
    if($a[2] == $b[2]){
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Comment: Example #2 on that page is very similar to what you're trying to do, take a look at that.

Comment: Wow, incredibly helpful answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

As of PHP >= 7.0 you can use usort in combination with the spaceship operator

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a[2] <=> $b[2];
    });
```

see: http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: short and powerful code. 
Thanks for save my day

Answer (score 5):

For database like patterns use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) as seen in example #3.

For example:

```
$sort = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
  $sort[$key]  = $row['basis'];
}
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

where `$data` is your data array and `basis` is the element used for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.4, you could use [`usort()`](https://php.net/usort), [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op), and [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) for a shorter code:

```
usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => $a[2] <=> $b[2]);
#                      ^         ^
#                      |         spaceship operator
#                      arrow function
```

Example:

```php
$arr = [
    ['105945', 'First name',  0.080878465391],
    ['109145', 'Second name', 0.0504154818384],
];
usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => $a[2] <=> $b[2]);
var_export($arr);
```

Output (condensed):

```
array (
  0 => array (0 => '109145', 1 => 'Second name', 2 => 0.0504154818384),
  1 => array (0 => '105945', 1 => 'First name',  2 => 0.080878465391),
)
```

You could also use scalar type declarations for a better type hinting:

```
usort($arr, fn(array $a, array $b): int => $a[2] <=> $b[2]);
```

Comment: Working demo : https://3v4l.org/kRSep

Answer (score -4):

see this page for example

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php
```

or example

```
      <?php 
function multisort($array, $sort_by) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $evalstring = '';
        foreach ($sort_by as $sort_field) {
            $tmp[$sort_field][$key] = $value[$sort_field];
            $evalstring .= '$tmp[\'' . $sort_field . '\'], ';
        }
    }
    $evalstring .= '$array';
    $evalstring = 'array_multisort(' . $evalstring . ');';
    eval($evalstring);

    return $array;
} 

$test = array(
    array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '3'),
    array( 'a' => '2', 'b' => '1'),
    array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '1'));

echo 'Unsorted: ';
print_r($test);

$result = multisort( $test , array('a','b') );

echo 'Sorted: ';
print_r($result);
?>

Result:

Unsorted: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 1
        )

)
Sorted: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: This is some very scary code - I highly suggest that you don't use it. Use `usort()` as recommended.

Comment: hey usort() function is already provided. So only i provide the alternative solution that i provide the example from manual.