# PHP multi sort array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

If I have this array:

```
array(
    [0] => array(5, "hi"),
    [1] => array(2, "hello"),
    [2] => array(9, "test")
)
```

How can I sort this array by [n][0]?
The end result should to be like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(9, "test")
    [1] => array(5, "hi"),
    [2] => array(2, "hello"),
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a multi-dimensional array by a 4th level value in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673835/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-a-4th-level-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom comparison function:

```
function multi_sort($a, $b)
{
    return $a[0] < $b[0];
}

usort($array, 'multi_sort');
```