# PHP: What is an efficient way to sort two arrays, which each contain objects with datetime properties?

Tags: php

Anyone know the best way to sort an array by date?  I would set the date as the array key but I don't want to overwrite anything with the same date. Thx in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidim sorts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590117/multidim-sorts) Otherwise, please provide more information. Why *two* arrays?

Comment: @deceze, they're two arrays of diff objects which I need to combine into one array and sort by time.  It appears as though usort() is my tool for the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a date array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a date array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
$merged = array_merge($array1, $array2);
usort($merged, function ($a, $b) { return $a->time - $b->time; });
```

The `$a->time` syntax depends on what exactly that object looks like, but you get the idea.

Comment: yup, this is exactly what I ended up doing.  Much appreciated, bud!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see without the date format posted or a code example. You could use the [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function to get them in the right order.  You just have to use the ISO (yyyy-mm-dd) format rather than the "english" format, and then get them in the right order with ksort.

If you are dealing with a multi-dimensional array, you could use [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to sort by keys with a callback. In the callback, simply parse the date to a timestamp, wich can easily be sorted.