# How do I order an array that contains arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort an array by a child array's value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672900/sort-an-array-by-a-child-arrays-value-in-php)

I have the following array structure:

```
$en_array = array();

while(...) {
    $en_array[] = $row;
}

$en_array = array (
    array (
        "name" => "a",
        "followers" => 5,
        "imageurl" => "http://images.com/img.jpg"
    )

    array (
        "name" => "b",
        "followers" => 25,
        "imageurl" => "http://images.com/img.jpg"
    )

    array (
        "name" => "c",
        "followers" => 15,
        "imageurl" => "http://images.com/img.jpg"
    )

)
```

In this example I would like to order the keys of en array by the values of followers, e.g. `$en_array[0]["followers"]` would have the value of `25`.

I'm not entirely sure if this can be done, but I hope it can.

Any help will be much appreciated :)!!

Comment: So we're sorting by followers, then?

Comment: Yeah, purely by followers :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you're *only* interested in sorting by followers, we can do this easily with PHP's [`usort`](http://php.net/usort).

```
function compare_by_followers($a, $b) {
    if($a['followers'] == $b['followers']) return 0;
    return $a['followers'] > $b['followers'] ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($en_array, 'compare_by_followers');
```

Sorting is, at its core, a process of comparing the array's elements to each other and figuring out which ones are greater than the others. `usort` allows you to use a custom comparison function for this process: `compare_by_followers($a, $b)` returns `-1` if `$a['followers']` is greater than `$b['followers']` (meaning that `$a` should go before `$b`), returns `1` if `$a['followers']` is less than `$b['followers']` (meaning that `$a` should come after `$b`), and returns `0` if they are equal.

Comment: Note that my first draft of this answer had it backwards and sorted in ascending order. If you're looking for descending, use the new snippet. (The only difference is I replaced the `<` in the function with `>`.)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the explanation!! So I take it that it gradually filters down comparing each array (I'm not really sure of what `$a` and `$b` represent)?

Answer (score 0):

[array_multisort()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is what you are after.

```
foreach ($en_array as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key] = $row['name'];
    $followers[$key] = $row['followers'];
}

array_multisort($followers,SORT_DESC,$name,SORT_ASC,$en_array);
```

After this, results are in descending order of followers, and where followers are the same, ascending order of name (i.e. alphabetical order).